# Firebase auth latest version not working in flutter application

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-app-check

I'm using firebase authentication to authenticate my users via phone authentication and the OTP message failed to send and the error I get is

> sms verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17499 Error code: 39

I've been searching for this error and I found out that the error may happen because missing play integrity configurations. I've already configure my SHAs keys and still throwing the same error and I've already add debug token for the play integrity and still the same thing happen again. Is this error from firebase side or what, because my older app version was working perfectly until I upgrade to app check?